# Library (JAR) default value for properties spring

Tags: java, spring, properties

I have an application that need to send emails. I might need later to send emails in a second application so I try to do a library to re-use it.

My application is done with Spring-boot.
My library just include Spring-core, Spring-context and Spring-test.

This is my EmailUtils in my library :

```
@Named
public class EmailUtils {

  @Value("${from}")
  private String from;

  @Value("${to}")
  private String to;
  ...
}
```

I would like to have a default file application.properties with that in the library :

```
from=default-from
to=default-to
```

now I would like if my application spring boot does something like that :

```
@Service
public void EmailService {

  @Inject
  private EmailUtils emailUtils;
  ...
}
```

I would like if I don't define a new application.properties in my application to get the default value from the library but would be possible to override them by using an application.properties in my Spring-boot app.

Info : My Spring-boot app have ScanComponent package (just to mention it). But my library has nothing. I don't know if I have to use a beans.xml and define a ContextPlaceHolder ...

I am a little bit loss, maybe there is a better way to do it ?

Thank you.

Comment: Arguably the best solution would be to keep Spring out of your library altogether, set `from` and `to` via constructor (or setters) and leave it to the client to provide the values, for instance reading from properties file if they wish so.

Comment: Yes I agree with you, but since all the env is done by spring ... I think it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am correctly understanding your question - you want to specify a default value for your `@Value` annotated properties. You can do this simply by simply using the format `@Value("${property_key:default value}")` so if you wished the default `from` value to be `me@me.com` and `to` to be `you@you.com` your code would read:

```
@Named
public class EmailUtils {

  @Value("${from:me@me.com}")
  private String from;

  @Value("${to:you@you.com}")
  private String to;
  ...
}
```